# xterm fonts display differently in RHEL6 and RHEL7

Tags: rhel, fonts, xterm

I was using RHEL6 for quite sometime and was happy using the xterm with the font of my choice. However, I had to move to RHEL7 recently, and then the problem of font display in xterm started. I have the same settings in ~/.Xresources file, but even then they display differently.

```
[sreb@hostname_rhel6 ~]$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-ia32:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-ia32:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-ia32:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.10 (Santiago)
Release:        6.10
Codename:       Santiago
[sreb@hostname_rhel6 ~]$ xrdb -query
Xcursor.size:   24
Xcursor.theme:  dmz-aa
Xcursor.theme_core:     true
Xft.antialias:  1
Xft.autohint:   0
Xft.dpi:        105
Xft.hinting:    1
Xft.hintstyle:  hintfull
Xft.rgba:       rgb
[sreb@hostname_rhel6 ~]$
```

In RHEL7, it is the same:

```
[sreb@hostname_rhel7 ~]$ xrdb -query
Xcursor.size:   24
Xcursor.theme:  dmz-aa
Xcursor.theme_core:     true
Xft.antialias:  1
Xft.autohint:   0
Xft.dpi:        105
Xft.hinting:    1
Xft.hintstyle:  hintfull
Xft.rgba:       rgb
[sreb@hostname_rhel7 ~]$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-ia32:core-4.1-noarch:cxx-4.1-ia32:cxx-4.1-noarch:desktop-4.1-ia32:desktop-4.1-noarch:languages-4.1-ia32:languages-4.1-noarch:printing-4.1-ia32:printing-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)
Release:        7.7
Codename:       Maipo
[sreb@hostname_rhel7 ~]$
```

Is there any other file which the xterm uses to display the fonts. If yes, which are those files (any commands to display the attributes/font-values of those files)?

Please suggest.

Regards,
Sreeram

Adding the image as per request.
In the image, the top XTERM is RHEL6, and the bottom XTerm is RHEL7.
Font I am using is LuxiMono (size 13).
[image: Font_Difference_In_RHEL6_RHEL7]

Comment: Ask the RedHat support!

Comment: Would you include screenshots of the two presentations, and the font name in qustion?

Comment: I have posted the screenshots. Any suggestions please ?

Comment: What does `appres XTerm|grep font:` tell you on RHEL6 and RHEL7?